# Send data on ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax

Is this the correct way to send data to server on ajax request?

```
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
          xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
              alert(response);
            }
          };
          xhttp.open("GET", "https://myurl/", true);
          xhttp.send(JSON.stringify("{ action: 'search', mode: question}"));
```

Because I get this error `405 (Method Not Allowed - Action not found)`

Comment: I can see five separate issues with this code, any of which I would consider to be wrong… in the general case. However: your question seems to be "How should I format my HTTP request to meet the expectations of this web service?" … and you've told us nothing about that service, so we have no way of knowing what it expects.

Answer (score 0):

No, there are several issues with that:

1. `alert(response);` will fail because there's no `response` variable; you'd probably want `alert(xhttp.responseText)`.
2. You're doing a GET, but then trying to send a POST body. You can't do that. GET information is in the URL, not the body.
3. You're sending JSON (well, trying to), but not identifying it as JSON.
4. You're passing a *string* into `JSON.stringify`, where normally you'd pass an object, not a string, as its job is to convert things *to* JSON strings.

Assuming you mean to do a POST, and you really do want to send JSON (e.g., that the server is set up to accept JSON from the client), then minimal changes would be:

```
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        alert(xhttp.responseText);                                    // 1
    }
};
xhttp.open("POST", "https://myurl/", true);                           // 2
xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");           // 3
xhttp.send(JSON.stringify({ action: 'search', mode: question}));      // 4
```

Note that I'm assuming `question` is an in-scope variable in that.

Comment: I still get this error `405 (Method Not Allowed - Action not found)`

Comment: @af_inb: Then as Quentin said, there's more to what the endpoint you're calling requires. This fixes the issues that we can fix with what little information we have.